# Using Multiple Metric Evaluation with GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I am attempting to use multiple metrics in GridSearchCV.  My project needs multiple metrics including "accuracy" and "f1 score".  However, after following the sklearn models and online posts, I can't seem to get mine to work.  Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
clf = KNeighborsClassifier()

param_grid = {'n_neighbors': range(1,30), 'algorithm': ['auto','ball_tree','kd_tree', 'brute'], 'weights': ['uniform', 'distance'],'p': range(1,5)}

#Metrics for Evualation:
met_grid= ['accuracy', 'f1'] #The metric codes from sklearn

custom_knn = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid, scoring=met_grid, refit='accuracy', return_train_score=True)

custom_knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = custom_knn.predict(X_test)
```

My error occurs on the `custom_knn.fit(X_train,y_train)`.  Further more, if you comment-out the `scoring=met_grid, refit='accuracy', return_train_score=True`, it works.
Here is my error:

```
ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting.
```

Also, if you could explain multiple metric evaluation or refer me to someone who can, that would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Please post the error you see as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`f1` is a binary classification metric. For multi-class classification, you have to use `averaged f1` based on different aggregation. You can find the exhaustive list of scoring available in Sklearn [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#the-scoring-parameter-defining-model-evaluation-rules).

Try this!

```
scoring = ['accuracy','f1_macro']

custom_knn = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid, scoring=scoring, 
                          refit='accuracy', return_train_score=True,cv =3)
```

Comment: Thank yo so much! That worked.  Now, trying to understand:  My knn classifier is now attempting to optimize the hyper parameters with accuracy AND f1 score as the overall metrics?

Comment: @TannerClark No, it will only optimize the scorer present in `refit`. So in above code, the `accuracy` is being optimized. `f1` is just monitored.

Comment: If one gets a Type error like I did, it is because refit is by default True, so if you use multiple scorings you either have to declare it as False or use a single scorer (either a value or a scoring function), but you must use the keyword.